# Is a Brownian Bridge less dispersed than a Brownian Motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, brownian-bridge

Consider the standard Wiener Process/Brownian Motion $W(t)$ on $[0,1]$ and the corresponding Brownian Bridge $B(t)=W(t)-\frac{t}{T}W(T)$. I am interested to know if the boundary crossing results for the Brownian motion provide a simple upper bound for the Brownian Bridge. Specifically, do we have for any function $f(t)$:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\exists t\in [0,1] \quad |W(t)|\geq f(t)) \geq \mathbb{P}(\exists t\in [0,1] \quad |B(t)|\geq f(t)) $$

More generally, if we consider two zero-mean Gaussian processes $S_1(t)$ and $S_2(t)$ with covariance functions $K_1(t,\tau)$ and $K_2(t,\tau)$, then if $K_1(t,\tau)\geq K_2(t,\tau)$ for all $t,\tau$, do we have:
$$ \mathbb{P}(\exists t\in [0,1] \quad |S_1(t)|\geq f(t)) \geq \mathbb{P}(\exists t\in [0,1] \quad |S_2(t)|\geq f(t)) $$

The result seems very intuitive but somehow I dont know where I should even start.

Comment: Second conjecture definitely wrong. Slightly higher variance doesn't compensate for min over more independent draws (consider extreme case of spatial independence vs constantness)

Comment: @Bananach I think it is true for the extreme case - if it is spatially independent, then the specified covariance function is zero at $t \neq \tau$ and >0 for $t=\tau$ while the constant zero-mean Gaussian process is always at 0 with covariance function of zero. And it is clear in this case that the inequality holds.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, you demand the inequality to good not just on the diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's almost vice versa. Namely, [Slepian's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slepian%27s_lemma) says that if $K_1(t,\tau)\geq K_2(t,\tau)$ for all $t, \tau $ **and** $K_1(t,t) =K_2(t,t)$ for all $t$, then $$\mathbb{P}(\exists t\in [0,1] \quad |S_1(t)|\geq f(t)) \leq \mathbb{P}(\exists t\in [0,1] \quad |S_2(t)|\geq f(t)).$$

On the bright side, the inequality you're interested in is true whenever $K_1 - K_2 $ is *positive semi-definite*; in fact, in this case $\mathbb{P}(S_1\in C) \leq\mathbb{P}(S_2\in C) $ for any convex symmetric $C$ (I'm not sure if this fact has a name).

In particular, it is applicable to the Brownian bridge and the Wiener process, since $B(t)$ and $W(T)$ are independent.

---

Here is the proof of the mentioned fact:

Since $\Delta K := K_1 - K_2$ is positive semidefinite, there exists a centered Gaussian process $X$ with covariance $\Delta K$. Since $K_1 = K_2 + \Delta K$, $S_1$ is distributed as $\widetilde S_2 + \widetilde X$, where $\widetilde S_2,\widetilde X$ are independent and have the same distributions as $S_2$ and $X$ respectively. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb P (S_1 \in C) = \mathbb{P}(\widetilde S_2 + \widetilde X\in C) = \mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{P}(\widetilde S_2 + h\in C)|_{h=\widetilde X_1}\big],
$$
where the last equality holds thanks to independence of $\widetilde S_2$ and $\widetilde X$.
Now by the Anderson inequality (see e.g. Lifshits *Lectures on Gaussian Processes*, Corollary 7.1), $\mathbb{P}(\widetilde S_2 + h\in C)\le \mathbb{P}(\widetilde S_2\in C)$, whence
$$
\mathbb P (S_1 \in C)\le \mathbb{P}(\widetilde S_2\in C) = \mathbb{P}(S_2\in C),
$$
as claimed.

Comment: Great answer. Do you have any reference for the unnamed fact?

Comment: @Bananach, I've checked some popular books and haven't found it, so I've written a short proof based on the Anderson inequality. Btw, do not forget to upvote and accept the answer if you think it's great :)

Comment: unfortunately I'm not the OP so can't accept, but thanks for the follow-up and for clarifying why the second part applies and fully solves to the example in the original question

Comment: Shouldn't there be equality on the diagonal for Slepian's inequality?

Comment: @Bananach, sure, thanks, fixed.